# Turn off "purple star" moments notifications on Twitter / X

Tags: twitter, notifications

On Twitter / X in 2023 I've started getting "purple star" notifications. I believe this is a notification for the "Moments" feature. They are basically algorithmic pushing of content from across the network; I do NOT want **notifications** for them.

[image]

Critically these add to the notifications badge number. This displays when you are using another account; causing you to constantly switch between accounts to clear these useless algorithmic advertising annoyances.

[image]

How can I disable notifications for these purple star tweets, but continue to receive notifications for the normal things on my account such as likes, DMs, and retweets?

Answer (score 3):

if you click on the three dots in the top right you can choose 'see less often'. I'm unaware of another way to get rid of them